# Can't interact with my smart contract

Tags: solidity

I decided to try my hand at web3 development and after deploying my token I ran into a problem. It is that I can't interact with my smart contract through the blockchain browser, it doesn't have the "Write Contract" tab when other tokens have it. I've been using OpenZeppelin Solidity Wizard for development.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you verify contract? If No, you have to verify the contract to see the "Write Contract: tab.

Then, If you have verified the contract, please check your SC function and make sure they have external/public function in order to appear in the "Write Contract" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your contract has methods that modify the state (such as changing variables, transferring tokens, etc.).  The blockchain explorer usually provides write functionality for methods that make state changes.